# Jquery -Ajax - How to read the nested JSON below

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following JSON  below and here is the  [fiddle and actual code](http://jsfiddle.net/dev2020/52pLuj3b/3/). I'm trying to read  all values in **filters**  so I can display all the values individually.
 **Example** 
"0.494765097719035" and 
"Accommodations" etc separately .

same for "azIndexDescPages"

**Example 2** 
azIndexDescPages

guid- 3B5470AA-4683-11DF-A523-8C6895261AFF

name -Information About Impacting Trees

shortURL- information-about-impacting-trees

I'm a little unsure of how get these values

How do I get the values **filters**, "alphabeticalGroup" and **azIndexDescPages** ?

//JSON

```
{
    "view": "search-category",
    "keyword": "Services",
    "filters": [{
        "0.494765097719035": "Accommodations"
    }, {
        "0.7564062477523095": "Support Services"
    }, {
        "OATH": "Administrative"
    }],
    "num-results": 20,
    "data": [{
        "alphabeticalGroup": "Services and Bags",
        "azIndexDescPages": [{
            "guid": "8A5C58E6-BECE-11DC-8E9F-96DAE110FEB8",
            "name": "General Vendor ",
            "shortURL": "general-vendor",
            "parenthicalCategory1": null,
            "parenthicalCategory2": null,
            "keyword": null,
            "shortDesc": "General Vendor blah blah.",
            "isRenew": true,
            "isApply": true,
            "descAmbiguousPages": null
        }]
    }, {
        "alphabeticalGroup": "Bages",
        "azIndexDescPages": [{
            "guid": "3B5470AA-4683-11DF-A523-8C6895261AFF",
            "name": "Information About Impacting Lorem",
            "shortURL": "information-about-lorem",
            "parenthicalCategory1": null,
            "parenthicalCategory2": null,
            "keyword": null,
            "shortDesc": "Lorem IPSUM Lorem IPSUM, etc.",
            "isRenew": null,
            "isApply": null,
            "descAmbiguousPages": null
        }, {
            "guid": "F560F636-4682-11DF-91AF-EA6C84051BF5",
            "name": "lorem ipsum 3",
            "shortURL": "information-about-lorem-ipsum-3",
            "parenthicalCategory1": null,
            "parenthicalCategory2": null,
            "keyword": null,
            "shortDesc": "New new new lorem ipsum.",
            "isRenew": null,
            "isApply": null,
            "descAmbiguousPages": null
        }]
    }]
}
```

//JavaScript

```
 function ajaxProcess() {

        var searchTerm = $("#term").val(); // get the user-entered search term on Enter key
        var URL2 = '/json/search-category-view.json';
        var tags = "&tags=" + searchTerm;
        //var tagmode="&tagmode=any";
        var jsonFormat = "&format=json";
        var ajaxURL = URL2 + "?" + tags + jsonFormat;


        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxURL,
            dataType: "json",
            //jsonp:"jsoncallback",
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                console.log("Data " + data);
                //var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log("data, textStatus, jqXHR " + data + textStatus + jqXHR)

                $.each(data, function(i, result) {
                    console.log(" i" + [i] + " --" + result);
                    console.log(" <br\>" + [i] + " --" + result.filters);
                    //if (result.filters) {
                        // html += '<div class="quote">';
                        $.each(data.filters, function(i, filter) {
                            console.log("<br>  filter " + [i] + " --" + filter['i']);
                            //html += '<div class="quote-line">' + line + '</div>';
                        });

                        $.each(data.data, function(k, data) {
                            console.log("<br> Data alphabeticalGrou " + [k] + " --" + data.alphabeticalGroup);
                            console.log("<br> Data azIndexDescPages" + [k] + " --" + data.azIndexDescPages);
                            //html += '<div class="quote-line">' + line + '</div>';
                        });


                   // }



                    var searchResult = "";
                    searchResult += "<br>" + result[i] + "ss " + i;
                    searchResult += "<br> keyword-- " + this['keyword'];

                    $("#gallery").append(searchResult).fadeIn(200);



                });

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('FAILED to get  JSON from AJAX call' + jqXHR + textStatus + errorThrown);

            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: your fiddle isn't working. please make your fiddle work and reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using a combination of json loops along with `Object.keys`, `eval` and some conditions and nested loops.. I don't think this is an optimal solution, but it does serve the need.... I think you can restructure your JSON object much better to get better performance and results

```js
//JSON
var jsonObject = {
    "view": "search-category",
    "keyword": "Services",
    "filters": [{
        "0.494765097719035": "Accommodations"
    }, {
        "0.7564062477523095": "Support Services"
    }, {
        "OATH": "Administrative"
    }],
    "num-results": 20,
    "data": [{
        "alphabeticalGroup": "Services and Bags",
        "azIndexDescPages": [{
            "guid": "8A5C58E6-BECE-11DC-8E9F-96DAE110FEB8",
            "name": "General Vendor ",
            "shortURL": "general-vendor",
            "parenthicalCategory1": null,
            "parenthicalCategory2": null,
            "keyword": null,
            "shortDesc": "General Vendor blah blah.",
            "isRenew": true,
            "isApply": true,
            "descAmbiguousPages": null
        }]
    }, {
        "alphabeticalGroup": "Bages",
        "azIndexDescPages": [{
            "guid": "3B5470AA-4683-11DF-A523-8C6895261AFF",
            "name": "Information About Impacting Lorem",
            "shortURL": "information-about-lorem",
            "parenthicalCategory1": null,
            "parenthicalCategory2": null,
            "keyword": null,
            "shortDesc": "Lorem IPSUM Lorem IPSUM, etc.",
            "isRenew": null,
            "isApply": null,
            "descAmbiguousPages": null
        }, {
            "guid": "F560F636-4682-11DF-91AF-EA6C84051BF5",
            "name": "lorem ipsum 3",
            "shortURL": "information-about-lorem-ipsum-3",
            "parenthicalCategory1": null,
            "parenthicalCategory2": null,
            "keyword": null,
            "shortDesc": "New new new lorem ipsum.",
            "isRenew": null,
            "isApply": null,
            "descAmbiguousPages": null
        }]
    }]
}
//CODE

jQuery.each(jsonObject, function(key, value) {
    
    if(key == "filters")
    {
        jQuery.each(value, function(nestedKey, nestedValue) 
        {
            var objectKey = Object.keys(nestedValue)[0];
            var objectVal = eval("nestedValue['"+objectKey+"']");
            //console.log(eval("nestedValue['"+objectKey+"']"));
            $("#filters").append(objectKey + '------------' +  objectVal + '<br/>' );
        });
        
    }
    
    if(key == "data")
    {
        jQuery.each(value, function(nestedKey, nestedValue) 
        {
            jQuery.each(nestedValue.azIndexDescPages, function(nestedKey, nestedValue) 
         {
                jQuery.each(nestedValue, function(nestedKey, nestedValue) 
    { 
                     console.log(nestedValue);
              $("#data").append(nestedKey + '------------' +  nestedValue + '<br/>' );
                     
                });
             
   });
            
            $("#data").append('<br /><br />');
             
        });
        
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filters">
    
    Filters : <br />
</div>
<br />
<div id="data">
    
    Data : <br />
</div>
```